# How can I randomize value of a variable between -5 to 21 without using constraints in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to randomize a variable which can take values from -5 to 21, $urandom_range generates only positive values and $random generates signed values but not a range

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int value;

value = $urandom_range(26)-5;
```